# Syntatic constructs of an xml - only Tags and PCDATA?

Tags: xml, xsd

Does XML contains only Tags and PCDATA as syntactic constructs? or is there anything more?

Cheers,

Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main constructs you encounter are tags, *entities* and text. There are others (notably: processing instructions, doctype declarations and the XML declaration) that are less common.

Entities are sequences of characters starting with a `&` and ending with a `;`, and you normally encounter them for things like `&gt;` and `&amp;` and so on. They stand for other things (like particular characters, but those aren't the only possibilities).

The XML declaration is the sequence that starts with `<?xml` and ends with `?>` that goes at the beginning of your document. It looks similar to a processing instruction (which also begins with `<?`) but formally isn't.

Doctype declarations begin with `<!` and are where you should get an XML library instead of trying to decode things by yourself; the document type system is *complicated!*